# Error! .NET Acquisition Failed: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Today I launched VSCode and found this error. How to fix it?

Error:

[image]

ms-dotnettools.csharp requested to download the .NET Runtime.
Downloading .NET version(s) 7.0.11~x64 ..................... Done!
.NET 7.0.11~x64 executable path: c:\Users\knyzs\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime.dotnet\7.0.11~x64\dotnet.exe

Error!
.NET Acquisition Failed: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\Users\knyzs\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime.dotnet\7.0.11\dotnet.exe'

Comment: i just added pre installed dotnet sdk to C# setting 
dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath:[
{
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
]

Answer (score 0):

The new C# Dev kit for VS Code needs .NET Runtime 7, which I didn't have installed.

I fixed this by installing .NET SDK 7 to the default location, under C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk.